# Get WooCommerce order date time on emails

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

I have the below function which I've added to a couple of places on the front end of my site, to show estimated delivery date based on the current date:

```
<?php $del_from = date('jS F', strtotime("+10 days"));
      $del_to = date('jS F', strtotime("+30 days"));
      $html = "Order today for estimated delivery between <b>{$del_from}</b> and <b>{$del_to}</b>. <a href='deliveryinfopageURL' target='_blank'>Read more about delivery</a>.";

   echo $html;
?>
```

I would like to include this in the shipment notification email (with slightly different text), but rather than using the current date + X days I'd like to use the order date + X days instead, as that's when the fulfilment process starts. Is this possible?

Also is there anything else that would need to change in order for this to work in a WooCommerce email template? Such as changing the way the hyperlink is placed in the text?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Yes I know how to do that, but I don't know how I can reference the order date in the email content.  So far I've only ever added static text. Thanks

Comment: @LoicTheAztec That's the kind of thing I don't know and sounds like what I'm looking for. I'm not a PHP or WooCommerce developer so I'm asking how I can access/reference the order date details to use them in the email template.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Great, thank you :)

Comment: Finally I answer below … Take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most Email templates or email hooks, the `WC_Order` object `$order` is accessible, so you can use one of the following `WC_Order` methods:

- `get_date_created()`,
- `get_date_modified()`,
- `get_date_paid(`),
- `get_date_completed()`

and you will get `WC_DateTime` object that you can use in your code like:

```
<?php 
    $order_datetime  = $order->get_date_created(); // Get order created date ( WC_DateTime Object ) 
    $order_timestamp = $order_datetime->getTimestamp(); // get the timestamp in seconds
    $day             = 86400; // 1 day in seconds

    $delivery_url    = 'deliveryinfopageURL'; // <== Set the correct URL to the delivery page
    $delivery_txt    = __("Read more about delivery", "woocommerce");

    // Output / display
    printf( 
        __('Order today for estimated delivery between %s and %s. %s', "woocommerce"),
        '<strong>'.date('jS F', $order_timestamp + (10 * $day) ).'</strong>',
        '<strong>'.date('jS F', $order_timestamp + (30 * $day) ).'</strong>',
        '<a href="'.$delivery_url.'" target="_blank">'.$delivery_txt.'</a>'
    );
?>
```

It should work on email templates.

> If the `WC_order` object is not accessible, but you can access the related `WC_email` object `$email` and get the `WC_Order` object with: `$order = $email->object;`

Comment: Thank you. Our of curiosity, could this also be accessed in the My Account pages? For example on the order details page?

Comment: @Lyall On order details page the related template is [order/order-details.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/order/order-details.php) called on the template [myaccount/view-order.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/myaccount/view-order.php)…If you look on both templates code the WC_Order object is defined using the variable $order, so yes you can use the same code…